# Exporting salesforce record dynamically using data loader

Tags: apex, data-loader, schedulebatch

I am using Data loader using command line interface(CLI) to export salesforce data
in my local system. Also using Windows scheduler   to schedule this task on daily basis.

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="Account" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" singleton="false">
        <description>Import Account Data.</description>
        <property name="name" value="Account" />
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="true"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="C:\Users\Ravikant Maurya\Desktop\Key1.og"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://login.salesforce.com"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.Server host" value="https://www.salesforce.com"/>

                <entry key="sfdc.username" value="*****************"/>
                <!-- password below has been encrypted using key file, therefore it will not work without the key setting: process.encryptionKeyFile
                the password is not a valid encrypted value, please generate the real value using encrypt.bat utility -->
                <entry key="sfdc.password" value="******************"/>
                <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="C:\User\Desktop\Key.txt"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.useBulkApi" value="true"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="500"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.externalIdField" value="id"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="10000"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select Id, Name, Phone, AccountNumber FROM Account"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
                <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\samples\conf\accountMasterMap.sdl"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="C:\Users\Desktop\CSV\CLI\Account.csv"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
                <entry key="process.initialLastRunDate" value="2005-12-01T00:00:00.000-0800"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It's working fine and account record is exported in Account.csv file specify by dataAccess.name tag.

My problem is when next day task is running it's override the previous record 
Account.csv, but i want to create a new record file every day.

I think i have to make  dataAccess.name  dynamic for each day but i don't know how to do this, if you have any solution to achieve this it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SETTING UP DATA LOADER 9.0 FOR AUTO PROCESSES](http://www.developerforce.com/media/Cheatsheet_Setting_Up_Automated_Data_Loader_9_0.pdf) cheatsheet there is an entry key that will help here:

> **Parameter**
>
> <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="C:\Program
>   Files\salesforce.com\Apex Data Loader 9.0\test\ extract.csv" />
>
> **Description:**
>
> Signifies the location and file name of
>   the dataaccess type process.
>   If running a csvRead, the process will
>   look for the file in this location.
>   *If running a csvWrite, **the process will
>   replace the file in this location**.*

There is an example of this in the [dataloader source code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/blob/0fcc4001c2c977686ee0f8b569cb4da0b7db158c/src/main/resources/templates/process-conf.xml#L86).

```
<bean id="extractAccountCsvProcess"
      class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
      singleton="false">
  <description>extractAccountCsv job gets account info from salesforce and saves info into a CSV file."</description>
    <property name="name" value="extractAccountCsvProcess"/>
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select Id, Name, Type, Phone, AccountNumber__c, Website, AnnualRevenue, 
                LastModifiedDate, Oracle_Id__c, CustomDateTime__c FROM Account where AccountNumber__c like 'ACCT%'" />
            <entry key="process.outputSuccess" value="@TEST_FILE_DIR@/status/extractAccountCsvSuccess.csv"/>
            <entry key="process.outputError" value="@TEST_FILE_DIR@/status/extractAccountCsvError.csv"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="@TEST_FILE_DIR@/status/extractAccountCsvSoapTrace.log"/>
            <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
            <!-- <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="@TEST_FILE_DIR@/data/extractAccountCsvMap.sdl"/> -->
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="@TEST_FILE_DIR@/data/extractAccountCsv.csv"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You then need a mechanism to automate replacing the dataAccess.name entry. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be possible to simply provide a value as a parameter at the command line - [Apex Data Loader PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer/Dynamic Property Replacement](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009h3UIAQ)

Instead you will need to use an additional process to modify the static process-conf.xml file with the required file name.

There are examples in:

- [Scripting the Apex Data Loader via Ant](https://force201.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/scripting-the-apex-data-loader-via-ant/)
- [Automate Command Line Dataloader using ANT with Dynamic arguments and SOQL query](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/automate-command-line-dataloader-using-ant-with-dynamic-arguments-and-query/)

In both cases, ANT is used to replace tokens in a template with the desired file name to create the static file that the batch job is then run against.

You could probably also achieve something similar without using ANT. See 
[How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60034/54026)

---

Another option would be to make the output file name unique after the data loader CLI operation has completed. I.e. After the export completes, if a file exists with the name Account.csv, rename it to something unique using the current date.

E.g.

```
if exist Account.csv ren Account.csv Account_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%-%DATE:/=%.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel , I am not able to append current date in Account.csv. Can you give me example how to do this?

Comment: @RaviKant It doesn't appear to be possible to parameterize  the output file name from the command line. You will need to modify the `process-conf.xml` dynamically before performing the export or modify the expected output file after the export has occured.

Comment: Thanks Daniel , I think I need  to write a batch file to rename the  file after the export has occurred.

Comment: @RaviKant Yes, that could be one of the simpler solutions. I've put a sample command to rename the CSV file at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per the SFDC documentation, you can set the parameters in the file at the run time. Please have a look at the documentation snip: 
[image]

So, as process.operation=insert can be set at runtime, we can also set dataAccess.name. 
I have never used CLI so I am not sure if it works. Please let me know if it works. :)

Thanks,
Shailesh

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact requirement and found a snippet of dos batch command that will set a numeric variable to the day of the week.  In my case I made 7 directories: c:\dataloader\backup\1  c:\dataloader\2 ... c:\dataloader\backup\7

And my batch file:

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)
call process.bat c:\dataloader\samples\conf csvAccountExtractProcess
call process.bat c:\dataloader\samples\conf csvOppExtractProcess
call process.bat c:\dataloader\samples\conf csvAddressExtractProcess
...
copy c:\dataloader\backup\*.csv c:\dataloader\backup\%DayOfWeek% /Y /V
```

The batch exports the data into the backup directory and then copies and overwrites the files in each day of week directory.

In Windows scheduler I execute the batch from the bin directory - "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin\sf-datax.cmd", and in the settings the scheduler starts the program from "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin\".

Comment: When I did this the file renamed to "2" ...

Answer (score 1):

Data loader properties **can** be set dynamically in the command line.

From https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader README

> The command-line version runs with whatever properties you have in your config.properties file, but you can also pass paramters at runtime as arguments to the program.
>
> For example, the following command sets the operation to insert regardless of what settings are contained in the config.properties file:

```
java -cp target/dataloader-xx.0-uber.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=CONFIG_DIR com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner process.operation=insert
```

I would recommend extending (or creating another) process.bat file to support these parameters, instead of hard-coding it in process.bat. To do so, open process.bat and find this line

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp ..\dataloader-42.0.0-uber.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%1 com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner %PROCESS_OPTION%
```

and add %3% at the end like this

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp ..\dataloader-42.0.0-uber.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%1 com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner %PROCESS_OPTION% %3%
```

Then when running process.bat add the parameter(s) in quotes

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin\"
process.bat ../myconfigdir AccountExport "dataAccess.name=C:\OutputDir\output %mydate%_%mytime%.csv"
```